# call method from another activity

Tags: java, android

I want in my second class call a method from first class. Method in  first class is:

```
 public void runLink( final Context context,final String link){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage(LocaleController.getString("Loading", R.string.Loading));
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // other code
  }
```

And in second class i have this:

```
First f=new First();
f.runLink(getActivity(),"BmJblT5G2bQEaSI6D6Q1Mw");
```

but when i run it my app will be stop, and log cat reference my error for this line of first class:

```
 final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: You cannot create activity like this: `new First()` ... also it seems like `runLink` should be a util **static** method ... and obviously instead using `this` you should use first method's parameter there

Comment: make this method in other activity where u call, and pass information via intent

Comment: use context instead of this ` final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace This Line

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

with this

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to replace 'this' with 'context'.
The reason is, that when you call 'runLink()' from the second class, the 'this' parameter refers to the first class's Context, which is not active.

Comment: thanks all. I find mistake. please forgive me for bad question